# Visual Leak Detector Crash

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, ogre3d, visual-leak-detector

I am using Visual Leak Detector to detect memory leaks in my program. When the program has finished running, I get an assertion triggered by the following code in **utility.cpp**. When Visual Leak Detector's header is excluded from the program, the program runs and exits without incident.

```
// Get the *real* address of the import. If we find this address in the IAT,
// then we've found that the module does import the named import.
import = GetProcAddress(exportmodule, importname);
assert(import != NULL); // Perhaps the named export module does not actually export the named import?
```

I am not sure why the assert is being triggered. Does anybody have an idea in what scenarios the assertion can be triggered?

Thanks

Comment: What are the values of exportmodule (name of the DLL) and importname (name of the function)?  Possibly Visual Leak Detector patches the DLL's import table, which might explain this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Patrick. I cannot debug the line itself. The assertion window dissappears as soon as I click somewhere (anywhere). Most of the time, I get the 'error' sound from windows without the window even popping up. For now I have moved away from VSD and settled on the standard leak detection instead. Not the ideal solution, but in this case I had very little choice.

Comment: This bug fixed in latest source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using ogre3d + vld and I get same issue!
I debugged the error code with GetLastError(): 
ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND, error 127: The specified procedure could not be found.

The good thing is, that it works(tested with "new char[20]") if you comment out that assertation and recompile,
but if you forget to call "delete Ogre::Root::getSingletonPtr();" it wont be detected :(

Edit: To report assertations to the debug console you can use this:

```
        // Get the *real* address of the import.
    import = GetProcAddress(exportmodule, importname);

    if(import == NULL){
        DWORD err=GetLastError(); 
        WCHAR buff[2048];
        wcsncpy_s(buff, 2048, L"\n============================================\nImport name: ", _TRUNCATE);
        int i=wcslen(buff);
        int n=0;
        //cast to unicode
        while(importname[n]){
            buff[i++]=importname[n++];
        }
        buff[i]=0;
        wcsncat_s(buff, 2048, L"\nExport module: ", _TRUNCATE);
        i=wcslen(buff);
        GetModuleFileName(exportmodule,&buff[i],2048-i);
        wcsncat_s(buff, 2048, L"\nError code: ", _TRUNCATE);
        i=wcslen(buff);
        _itow_s(err,&buff[i],2048-i,10);
        wcsncat_s(buff, 2048, L"\n============================================\n", _TRUNCATE);
        report(buff);
    }
    //assert(import != NULL); // Perhaps the named export module does not actually export the named import?
```

Result will be:

```
============================================
Import name: CoGetMalloc
Export module: C:\data\projects\Avenon\trunk\source\..\build\Avenon_d.exe
Error code: 127
============================================

============================================
Import name: CoTaskMemAlloc
Export module: C:\data\projects\Avenon\trunk\source\..\build\Avenon_d.exe
Error code: 127
============================================

============================================
Import name: CoTaskMemRealloc
Export module: C:\data\projects\Avenon\trunk\source\..\build\Avenon_d.exe
Error code: 127
============================================
```

Comment: Hi Sajty, thanks for the reply. You are right, it does work but ogre's pointers fail to get detected if they are leaked. Still it is better than the standard leak detector. Thanks again!

Comment: UPDATE: It randomly stopped working for me again. I have compiled against release and debug and checked with both (commented out the asserts) and the same problem persists. The worst part is that a window shows for a split second before it disappears so I cannot know what happened. My debug output shows: 

First-chance exception at 0x7589b727 in ProjectName.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: OIS::Exception at memory location 0x003cf2d4.. =( ... very sad because when it works, it works wonders

Comment: Hi! I have used it a lot and I used OIS keyboard and mouse too, and no crash. Try it without vld for a time, if it throws exceptions too, then its not vld. I use dbghelp from windows7 system32 folder which is v6.1.7600.16385

Answer (score 1):

try using a different debugger to check the leak. I would use deleaker